# JavaScript, why am I getting the error "array is not defined in the function add"

Tags: javascript, object

Here is my code

```
var chars = new function() {
  this.array = new Array(0);
  this.add = function(x, y, speed, size, color, ai) {
    this.array[array.length] = {x: x, y: y, size: size, color: color, ai: ai};
  }
}
```

On line 35, the only line in the function add I am getting the error "array is not defined" why is this happening and yes I did try,

```
chars.array[array.length] = {x: x, y: y, size: size, color: color, ai: ai};
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the code formatting to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to fix it to:

```
var chars = new function() {
    this.array = new Array(0);
    this.add = function(x, y, speed, size, color, ai) {
        this.array[this.array.length] = {x: x, y: y, size: size, color: color, ai: ai};
    }
}
```

I have changed `this.array[array.length]` to `this.array[this.array.length]`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. The push method appends values to an array.

```
 this.array.push({x: x, y: y, size: size, color: color, ai: ai});
```